# Error when trying to install steam with "sudo apt-get install steam"

Tags: command-line, steam

Here is the error message:

```
ILocalize::AddFile() failed to load file "public/steambootstrapper_english.txt".
[2017-02-14 16:35:18] Startup - updater built Jun 16 2014 11:16:02
Xlib:  extension "NV-GLX" missing on display ":0".
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
steam
```

Answer (score 0):

First try:

```
sudo add-apt-repository multiverse
sudo apt update && sudo apt install steam
```

then should run steam.

If it´s not the problem try [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2275526) posted by sejvenables. Maybe can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Manually download and install the latest Steam .deb from their site (http://store.steampowered.com/about).  This worked when I installed Steam on my desktop a couple of weeks ago.